# First cell always empty in table. Display only from the second cell - Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view which display the contacts from array. I setup the table view delegates by follows.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [contactArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ContactCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [contactArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 60.0;

}
```

But the first cell in the table view always empty. It starts display only from second cell. I thought it may be header view. So I removed the header using the following delegate methods.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.0;

}
```

But still have the problem. I attached the screenshot about this issue. [image: screenshot]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you fill `contactArray`?

Comment: set cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indecPath.row]; and see where your tableView's cell is started .

Comment: @iPatel The table cell is supposed to be started from the origin of the table view. But it is starting with the gap from the table view origin. When I scroll it fill those gap. Don't know what the exact problem is.

Comment: you might have accidentally dragged the `tableView` downwards in _storyBoard_. Check the `Y` value of the `tableView` in the `size inspector`.

Comment: @GoGreen Y value is good

Comment: in second image table view cell display all same title could you change your iamge as tableview index

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `TableView` is fine and it is working correctly, this is due to some other problem that is included in `iOS 7`, that automatically scroll insets. To solve this problem, go to your storyboard and select the viewcontroller in which your `TableView` is and select the `ViewController` and select the `Properties` of that `ViewController`, and uncheck this checkbox, which is read as `Adjust ScrollView Insets`. See this screen shot,

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your table is correct.Just your table was auto adjusted by the viewController.
You can write `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;`

Answer (score 0):

Your Deduction is wrong your first cell isn't missing, but your tableview has started by 64 points down. So change your frame of your tableview or your tableview constraints accordingly.
Tip : Try setting a background colour when you have to debug things like this to clear your doubts.